# set default value of a column extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

here, i have some columns in a grid and i want to give default value in the 'receivedquantity' field and by default the received quantity filed will be equal to "Quantity" field.if user edits the field then data will come from the database.I am using mvc pattern here...

```
this.columns=
    [
    {
    header:'name',
    dataIndex:'name'},
    {
    header:'Quantity',
    dataIndex:'quantity',
    },
    {
    header:'Received Quantity',
        dataIndex:'receivedquantity',
        selectOnFocus: true,
        filterable:true,
        renderer:function(val, meta, record){
        var receivedquantity = record.data.receivedquantity;
var quantity=record.data.quantity;
        if(receivedquantity==0)//by default receivedquantity=0
        {
        //set (receivequantity=quantity) in the grid's received quantity cell 
        }},
     editor: {allowBlank:false
     }
            }
                ];
```

Comment: Do you want the default value to just be displayed in the grid, or to be represented in the store?

Comment: From you edit I gather you just want it rendered..

Comment: for now, only need to display

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
renderer: function(val, meta, record){
    if(val) return val;
    return record.get('quantity');
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.. can you try and be more verbose?